# Nonlinear regression:fit data to curve

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have read a number of Matlab documents but to no avail I was unable to solve the following problems concerning non-linear regression. I have a single observation vector consisting of 200 measurements `y`. The model is unknown. The command `nlinfit(x, y, modelFun)` needs a model as an input but I was wondering if there is something like `polyfit` which may give the coefficients for nonlinear regression.

Will be obliged if the following questions are cleared

1. How do I fit the data without knowing the model using nonlinear regression?
2. After the data is fit, is there a way to determine which model is being followed i.e whether it is an NAR, NARMA, NMA.

Comment: You should clarify your question: Do you want a time series model? What is nma?

Comment: polyfit gives the coefficients only if you supply a model too, i.e. the order of the polynomial. You can't get an analytically model from data completely blindly, you need to at least decide on a general form of a model before hand. All the regression can do is find the coefficients (or parameters) that make your model most closely resemble your data. If you want regression on data without specifying a model then perhaps you need a black box approach like neural networks?

Comment: @Dan: Given the question that was asked I think it is important to emphasize taht a neural network is no less a model than a polynomial, it just has more parameters. It's a composition of linear combinations of sigmoid functions (typically). The "backtracking" algorithm is an instance of gradient descent in parameter space.

Comment: @DCS: I agree with that. I guess it's just a case of how expressive you want your model to be. My interpretation of the question is that the OP wants to end up with a model that he can read an understand, NNs won't provide that which is why I called it a black box approach. But yes, it is just regressing a more complicated (more parameters at least) model, but a very general model that is likely to fit many shapes of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no such thing as non-linear regression without model!** This is a conceptual issue and not a programming or Matlab problem. Nonlinear regression minimizes, by definition, the error between a model and your data, under a certain error metric, by searching the space of the model's parameters.

What you can do is fit and test a couple of models (e.g. Polynomials with increasing degree) with your data and evaluate which one fits best without over fitting. But you as the expert for your data have to chose which models you test.

Polynomial fitting in Matlab can be computed with `polyfit`, by the way.

**Regarding your questions**

> The thing is I have used polyfit and got some coefficients say a,b,c,d. So, it is a nonlinear 4th order equation.(A)Should I then use this equation as a parameter when using nlfit which asks for a model?

You don't need to call `nlfit` after `polyfit`. `polyfit` does the complete fitting of a polynomial mode. The coefficients you get fully describe the polynomial that models your data. Look in the doc how you plot the polygon against your data, and how to evaluate the quality of the fit.

> Will nlfit give better coefficients,what is the benefit of doing nlfit over polyfit?

`nlfit` is a more general model fitting method. With `nlfit` you can fit your own model, but you have to implement your model and provide it to `nlfit`. `polyfit` on the other hand only fits polynomial models. You can think of it as a highly specialized version of `nlfit`, made to fit only one type of model (namely polynomials). `nlfit` will not give you better coefficients if you feed it with a polynomial model.

> (B)How do I know that the obtained equation is following an AR model or MA model or ARMA model?

I'm not an expert in these models, but I think AR / MA / ARMA are different types of models, so `polyfit` will not tell you anything about these.

Comment: The thing is I have used polyfit and got some coefficients say a,b,c,d. So, it is a nonlinear 4th order equation.(A)Should I then use this equation as a parameter when using nlfit which asks for a model?(B)How do I know that the obtained equation is following an AR model or MA model or ARMA model?(C) Will nlfit give better coefficients,what is the benefit of doing nlfit over polyfit?

Comment: @RiaGeorge: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @DCS said, You should have a model.

However, you must be trying to say that you don't know which model to use... This the problem that everyone faces when they are trying to estimate any model. Unless you have some theory to justify your choice, the best way is to start with the simple models.

If you have a time series model, I mean you intend to explain the actual value of y using old values, my suggestion is that you start using the models in this order:

1) AR model

2) ARMA model

and then you can try more complicated models such as nar or narma.

There are some ways to compare models such as akaike http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/aic.html

It seems that you are not very acquainted with econometrics. If this is case I suggest you the book of Walter Enders... It is a very simple introduction to the theme.

Comment: The thing is I have used polyfit and got some coefficients say a,b,c,d. So, it is a nonlinear 4th order equation.(A)Should I then use this equation as a parameter for "modelfun" when using nlfit which asks for a model?(B)How do I know that the obtained equation is following an AR model or MA model or ARMA model?(C) Will nlfit give better coefficients,what is the benefit of doing nlfit over polyfit?